# why would windbindd send SMBv1 message to AD/DC?

Tags: debugging, multiprocessing, samba

I have an Windows AD/DC that has a firewall setting to monitor when SMBv1 messages come across.  Recently, it started reporting that one of my Samba servers is sending a Negotiate Protocol Message (confirmed via Wireshark) requesting SMBv1 protocols.  Samba version 4.11.2
Anyone have an idea of why such would be occurring?

I've tried using gdb to walk winbindd through to the offending request, but it fork()s too many times to follow via gdb - looking for other suggestions.